# Flutter CustomTimerPainter how can we run this in background so the timer wont stop on dispose

Tags: flutter

Here is the complete code of myclass what i am trying to do here is i am running a timer and when the timer reachs 0 it shows an ad but when the application is closed the timer is also stopped is there anyway that timer runs in background as well and don't stop . i've tried putting `String _ab = '45';` and save its state but it didn't work it just saves the time reamaining but when the application is closed the timer also stops there, Google it alot but didn't find any solution for this . A help in this would be really good

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';


class Showads extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CountDownTimer(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        accentColor: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}

const String testDevice = 'MobileId';

class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();
}
String _ab = '45';
class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
    keywords: <String>['Game', 'Mario'],
  );

  InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
  RewardedVideoAd videoAd = RewardedVideoAd.instance;
  bool _interstialadValue = false;

  InterstitialAd createInterstitialAd() {
    return InterstitialAd(
        adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
      //Change Interstitial AdUnitId with Admob ID
        targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          print("IntersttialAd $event");
        });
  }
      int _coins =0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    //Change appId With Admob Id
     videoAd.listener =
      (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
    print("REWARDED VIDEO AD $event");
    if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
      setState(() {
        _coins += rewardAmount;
      });
    }
  };

  videoAd.load(
    adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId,
    targetingInfo: targetingInfo);

    super.initState();
     if(_ab == '00'){
      setState(() {
        _ab ='40';
      });
    }
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: int.parse(_ab)),
      );
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    if(_ab == '00'){
      setState(() {
        _ab ='40';
      });
    }
    print(timerString);
    print(timerString.substring(2, 4));

    setState(() => _ab = timerString.substring(2, 4));
    print(_ab);
    setState(() =>  controller);
    _CountDownTimerState().dispose();
    controller.dispose();
    if(_interstialadValue){
    _interstitialAd.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child:
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    height:
                    controller.value * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: CustomTimerPainter(
                                        animation: controller,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                                      )),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Next AD Timer ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Minimize App \n Do not close",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        timerString,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 112.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedBuilder(
                          animation: controller,
                          builder: (context, child) {
                            return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (controller.isAnimating) {
                                    //controller.stop();
                                     createInterstitialAd()
                                      ..load()
                                      ..show();
                                      setState(() {
                                        _interstialadValue = true;
                                        print(controller.value);
                                        print(timerString);
                                      });
                                  }
                                  else {
                                   // videoAd.show();
                                   showRewardedAd();

                                   // Checkout();
                                    controller.reverse(
                                        from: controller.value == 0.0
                                            ? 1.0
                                            : controller.value);
                                  }
                                },
                                icon: Icon(controller.isAnimating
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow),
                                label: Text(
                                    controller.isAnimating ? "WAIT ADS LOADING" : "WATCH AD"));
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
  void showRewardedAd() async {
    try {
      await videoAd.load(
    adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId,
    targetingInfo: targetingInfo);;

      await videoAd.show();
    } 
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
}





class CustomTimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CustomTimerPainter({
    this.animation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
    paint.color = color;
    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, -progress, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomTimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
        color != old.color ||
        backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sugget you to try to use an isolate.

You may want to check this article for complete example and explanations: https://codingwithjoe.com/dart-fundamentals-isolates/